# JSF:select many menu with resize component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, scroll

I have a `SelectManyMenu` that is scroolble, i want to add resize component to it but there is some problem:

1) my scrool pane does not resize

[image]

2) values of pane go out of pane on resize

[image]

```
 <h:form>
                            <p:selectManyMenu id="menu" value="#{bean.selectedCity}" label="cities"
                                              converter="#{cityConverter}" showCheckbox="true" scrollHeight="170"
                                              filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" style="width: 150px !important">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.cities}" var="c" itemValue="#{c}"
                                               itemLabel="#{c.name}"/>
                            </p:selectManyMenu>
                            <p:resizable for="menu" handles="e,s,se"/>
                        </h:form>
```

what is the problem? how can i solve it?

Comment: The problem is that the two do most likely not work together out of the box. What you can try to solve it is experiment with the css of the inner divs. And next time, think a little more carefully about the tags you choos. It is even better to add css instead of jsf I think

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it somwhow ?